# Add Framework to Project schemes instead of target on iOS Project

Tags: ios, frameworks, dynamic-linking

Add Framework to project scheme rather than target. I have debug framework it has to be tested only in debug scheme created and should not be added to the project by adding it in the Frameworks, Libraries in the General Tab of Xcode project.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add framework dynamically to a scheme. place below configurations in the config file. I want to use Alamofire only in debug scheme rather than adding it to the project target.

FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/Alamofire
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "Alamofire"